# Probability of alien species going extinct

Tags: probability, puzzle

One alien lands on a planet. Every day, the alien can perform the following actions, with their probabilities as: 
Self - destruct : 1/4 chance 
Do nothing - 1/4 chance
Split into three aliens - 1/4 chance 
Split into two aliens - 1/4 chance 
If the alien splits, each produced alien has the same probabilities. 
What is the probability of the species going extinct?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the probability of an alien and it's entire line dying out be D. So we can write D as

$D$ = $\frac14$(if it self destructs) +$\frac14$(if it does nothing)$\cdot$P(probability of going extinct tomorrow) + $\frac14$(if it splits into $3$)$\cdot$P(probability of all three going extinct) +$\frac14$(if it splits into $2$)$\cdot$P(probability of all two going extinct)

We can see that

P(probability of going extinct tomorrow) is same as today = $D$

P(probability of all three going extinct) = $D\cdot D\cdot D$ = $D^3$
as each of them has to go extinct which means it's an intersection of each dying case, which in case of independent events means multiplication.

Similarly, P(probability of all two going extinct) = $D\cdot D$ = $D^2$

Putting them in the equation gives us

$$D = \frac{(1+D+D^2+D^3)}{4}$$

$$D^3+D^2-3D +1 =0$$

This has $1$ as an obvious solutions, which helps us determine the other two $\sqrt{2}-1$ and $-\sqrt{2}-1$. Since probability cannot be negative, the latter is out of the question. Now between $1$ and $\sqrt{2}-1$, you can use either Expectation to see that number of aliens the next day will be $1.5>1$ which means there is non zero chance it might survive or you can use induction to get the fact that $P_k$(probability it goes extinct after $k$ days) is always less than $\sqrt{2}-1$, starting from $P_1$ which is $0.25$

This means

$$D = \sqrt{2}-1$$

Comment: Two years later and this answer just saved me! Thanks so much.